# Windows Spanned Disk (LDM) automount

Tags: ubuntu, mount, automount

Every time i startup the server with 2x2tb raid harddrive i need to call the following methods to mount:

```
ldmtool create all
mount /dev/mapper/ldm_vol_SPONS_SERVER-Dg0_Volume1 /media/data
```

Which is for sure not the ideal way. So for that reason i have been searching to automount and found following:

```
Add "[ -x /usr/bin/ldmtool ] && ldmtool create all >/dev/null || true" to the /etc/init/mountall.conf
Add an entry in the /etc/fstab file.
```

Now i tried many, many things. Tried with a bunch of UUID's in the fstab file.. but it always states: "The disk drive for /media/data is not ready yet or not present"

So i guess that Step 1 (the line added to mountall.conf) is wrong.. But as i'm not an expert in ubuntu and programming in it. I need some help to fix this one.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT

Currently i'm trying with the following line in the fstab file:

"/dev/mapper/ldm_vol_SPONS_SERVER-Dg0_Volume1 /media/data ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.utf8 0 0"

I also tried with some UUID's but it seems like the ldmtool needs to create the mapper, with an UUID won't be possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just add the known-good lines

```
ldmtool create all
mount /dev/mapper/ldm_vol_SPONS_SERVER-Dg0_Volume1 /media/data
```

to `/etc/rc.local` and be done with it? I am quite positive, you don't need those disks during the boot process!

Comment: your my hero today! Thanks this did the job!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still open or not, but I was able to easily mount the LDM volume in fstab. I did a blkid to get the UUID of Volume1:

/dev/mapper/ldm_vol_DARREN-PC-Dg0_Volume1: LABEL="Raid" UUID="1AF2CF94F2CF7295" TYPE="ntfs"

then was able to mount it just like any other ntfs volume.

In fstab:

UUID=1AF2CF94F2CF7295 /home/darren/raid ntfs defaults,rw,noatime 0      0